# Should try-catch block surround a function that catches all exceptions it throws?

Tags: java, exception

I'm new to exceptions handling in JAVA.  I have some basic question about it:

Inside First.java:

```
public void foo ()
{
  Second obj = new Second();
  obj.boo();
}
```

Inside Second.java

```
public void boo()
{
   try { /* may throw some I/O Exception here */ }
   catch (IOException e) { System.err.println(e.message()); }
   catch (Exception e) { System.err.println(e.message()); }
}
```

My question is, do we need to(Should we) add try/catch block inside the foo() method of First.java as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are catching the exception inside the boo() method you don't have too.

But instead if you would have throwed the exception for the calling method to handle it you would have  to handle the exception there..

```
public void boo() throws IOException{
//something raising IOException
}

public void foo(){
  try{
      Sound obj = new Sound();
        obj.boo();
} catch(IOException io) {

//handle your exception
}
}
```

Still if you don't want to handle the exception inside the foo() method you could choose to throw it again:

```
public void foo() throws IOException{
   //your code here
}
```

Again the method calling the foo() would have to handle the exception otherwise, it would result in an exception

Comment: So, if I include try/catch blocks for BOTH foo() and boo(). I guess the catch block in foo() will NEVER catch any exception am I correct? Since the try/catch block in boo() already catch everything!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to, but if you don't want to handle it in boo(), you could do the following:

```
public void boo() throws IOException{

...

}

public void foo(){
   try{
   boo();
   }catch(IOException ioe){ System.out.println(ioe.message());}
}
```

But what you have should work fine. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

No, that's actually a compile error (or warning?) as `boo` is nonthrowing (unless `Second`'s constructor throws).  Try it.

Comment: Everything are non-throwing. and yes I MUST put try/catch in the Second.java class boo() method.
The question is, I'm not sure whether I also need to add try/catch for First.java foo() method as well.  Because it call the obj.boo() method that may generate a IOexception.

Comment: boo may NOT throw an IOException in your code.  If a function catches exceptions thrown inside of it, those essentially "don't count," and they certainly do not count from the point of view of any calling function.

Comment: As I said, try it, and see what the compiler tells you.